# Spark error on ALS trainImplicit: assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 1

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark-mllib

I am getting below error when training ALS (implicit) using hadoop 2.6.1 and spark 1.5.2 on ubuntu 14

```
16/06/16 06:26:41 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
16/06/16 06:26:41 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
16/06/16 06:26:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 57.0 (TID 39, 172.17.0.10): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 1.
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$CholeskySolver.solve(ALS.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ml$recommendation$ALS$$computeFactors$1.apply(ALS.scala:1170)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ml$recommendation$ALS$$computeFactors$1.apply(ALS.scala:1131)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$41$$anonfun$apply$42.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$41$$anonfun$apply$42.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:700)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

------------------------------------------------
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$aggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1082)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.aggregate(RDD.scala:1075)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$.computeYtY(ALS.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$.org$apache$spark$ml$recommendation$ALS$$computeFactors(ALS.scala:1123)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$train$3.apply(ALS.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$train$3.apply(ALS.scala:575)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS.run(ALS.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$.trainImplicit(ALS.scala:417)

------------------------------
```

Can anyone let me know why BLAS is not getting loaded?